# Android Retrofit1.9.0 How to use common class for multiple method to save response

Tags: android, retrofit

**In this where I used to Book Class  to store my response. Instead of this class I would like to add multiple services. Please let me know how to use this kind situation.**

```
    private void getBooks() {
        //While the app fetched data we are displaying a progress dialog
        final ProgressDialog loading = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Fetching Data", "Please wait...", false, false);
        final String authorizationString = "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString(
                ("#username" + ":" + "#password").getBytes(),
                Base64.NO_WRAP);

    RequestInterceptor requestInterceptor = new RequestInterceptor() {
        @Override
        public void intercept(RequestFacade request) {

            request.addHeader("Authorization", authorizationString);

        }
    };

    //Creating a rest adapter
    RestAdapter adapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint(ROOT_URL)
            .setRequestInterceptor(requestInterceptor)
            .build();

    //Creating an object of our api interface
    BooksAPI api = adapter.create(BooksAPI.class);



    api.createUser(user, new Callback<Book>() {
        @Override
        public void success(Book book, Response response) {
            loading.dismiss();
            Log.i("s", "s");

            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
            String currentDateandTime = sdf.format(new Date());
            _time.append("\n Time After service  :" + currentDateandTime);

            Toast.makeText(context, "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
            loading.dismiss();
            Log.i("s", "etr");
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Try expanding your question. It is difficult to understand what you are asking.

Comment: Dear @mehrdad, I would like to call more than 2 different services using above single method. and wanna store data in different classes. So How can i get and store response in different classes.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your common code in any singleton class like application. Assuming your base url will be same so no need to create different service class like BookAPI but crate a single service file and put your all api there. Common code :-

```
RequestInterceptor requestInterceptor = new RequestInterceptor() {
    @Override
    public void intercept(RequestFacade request) {

        request.addHeader("Authorization", authorizationString);

    }
};

//Creating a rest adapter
RestAdapter adapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
        .setEndpoint(ROOT_URL)
        .setRequestInterceptor(requestInterceptor)
        .build();

//Creating an object of our api interface
BooksAPI api = adapter.create(BooksAPI.class);
```

BooksAPI api can be moved to class level and you can access it from activities by public method.

Comment: Thanks for ua answer@Ramit.. But here I wanna use two different services, I mean URL differs

Comment: api.createUser(user, new Callback<Book>() {
        @Override
        public void success(Book book, Response response) {}
                                                                                                                                   Here Callback<Book>() is a class which stores the response. When I am using multiple services storage classes may vary. So in that case how can I use Generic class..